# PhoneGap/Cordova Error: IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient "URL blocked by whitelist"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cors

When I build a debug APK using the instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Command-line%20Tools by running:

```
./build --debug
```

and deploy the resulting APK using:

```
abd -install <apk path>
```

I can install it find, but as soon as the app makes an API call I get the following error:

```
PhoneGap/Cordova Error: IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient "URL blocked by whitelist"
```

However when I build the localhost version, which is a yeoman angular ionic stack (see here:http://frontendmatters.com/getting-started-mobile-app-development-phonegap-yeoman-angularjs-ionic/) I have no such problem. My build process for that is

```
>grunt build
>grunt serve
```

I have found several other questions on SO with this error and they all reccomend adding the following line to your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

I have added this line to every file named config.xml in my project and rebuilt, out of desperation. Here they all are (perhaps this will give you a bit of context regarding my build process as I'm a bit confused on it myself):

```
./app/config.xml
./old_app/config.xml
./platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml
./platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
./www/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was two fold. First some of my configs had:

```
<access origin="*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

and second the proper build process for the app (at least I think) is this:

```
grunt build
phonegap build android
cd platform/adroid/cordova
./build --release
```

Those two pieces in place and everything was fixed